# What is the user centric business development model?

Tags: research, users

I've been asked to describe a user centric business development model to a lay person.

I say it is:
Research user behaviours > model users and workflows > define requirements and business needs > define solution framework > refine > iterate > finish.

This is obviously a very high level analysis but do you think it sounds about right? Correct order? Steps missing?

Comment: The only comment I might have is that it defines business needs awfully late when this could be done in tandem with researching user behaviours, non?

Answer (score 1):

Hi colmcq I guess your process is pretty good but I would add some changes to introduce the constant quality improvement needed.

I suggest:

1. Identify the user needs
2. Research about the context (who an when will need this)
3. Define the requirements
4. Define solution framework
5. Release the final product
6. Collect users feedback and  performance data.
7. Identify new needs.
8. Improve the model based on the information from point 6 and 7.

Steps 5 to 8 should be repeated continuosly to ensure the quality improvement, maybe this goes too far but I guess that constant improvements are a critical factor if you try to define the user centric business development model.

Comment: I guess that a user centered development model doesn't need to define the bussiness requirements, I mean, the requirements are  "to satisfy the user needs and get profit by doing so", on my view here "product requirements" should be after the needs research because you are trying to focus your work on that needs...

But, I guess I think so because I use to work for internal client, this means I already know the bussiness when I start working on product developments... Don't you think that proccess won't be the same for external / internal client?

Answer (score 1):

I agree, the business requirements are too late, I'd say they are usually the starting point.

I suggest something like this:

1. Business Requirement Analysis (What are we building and why)
2. Research (Contextual and User research)
3. User Requirement Analysis (Need analysis, Scenarios, Flows ect)
4. Iterative Design Process (Concept - Test - Refine)
5. Implementation

Of course Step 1.-4. can be iterative too.